# How could I simplify this Scala Option usage

Tags: scala

I have following code that get parameter and if it is valid ObjectId, converts it to Option[ObjectId] and otherwise, returns None.

I was thinking how it could be simplified, but didn't find anything particularly better.

Note: params.get("desiredImage") is Option[String]

```
val imageId: Option[ObjectId] = params.get("imageId") match {
  case None => None
  case Some(x) => {
    if (ObjectId.isValid(x)) {
      Some(new ObjectId(x))
    } else {
      None
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `filter`:

```
val imageId: Option[ObjectId] = params.get("imageId")
       .filter (ObjectId.isValid)
       .map(new ObjectId(_))
```

Comment: In the spirit of even less, you should be able to pass in isValid as `params.get("imageId") filter (ObjectId.isValid)`

Comment: I think your solution also needs a map to create the ObjectId

Answer (score 7):

You can also use collect to do it in a single operation:

```
val imageId: Option[ObjectId] = params.get("imageId") collect { 
  case x if ObjectId.isValid(x) => new ObjectId(x) 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can also use a for comprehension:

```
val imageId  = for ( x <- params.get("imageId") if ObjectId.isValid(x)) 
                   yield new ObjectId(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

For your own piece of code you have a nice option to cut it a little by using `case ... if`:

```scala
val imageId: Option[ObjectId] = params.get("imageId") match {
  case Some(x) if ObjectId.isValid(x) => Some(new ObjectId(x))
  case _ => None
}
```